# compress a SQL backup file through winrar

Tags: batch-file, rar

I am using the below commands in windows batch file to rar a backup file in the `C:\temp` folder.

I don't know why is not working and is not showing any errors

```
ECHO OFF
for /f %%a in ('date /t') do set DAY=%%a
SET rarFile=C:\temp\DATA%DAY%Backup.rar
echo 
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar" a -r -df %rarFile% C:\temp\*Backup.bak
```

Comment: Turn `ECHO ON` at the top of your script and run the script from the command prompt instead of using your mouse. Copy and paste all the output from the console into your question by editing it.

Comment: Take a look at the output of your `date /t` command and see if it contains characters, like **`/`**, which are disallowed in Windows file names. You could then consider doublequoting `%rarFile%`.

Comment: Why do you want the file name with date in the middle between `DATA` and `Backup`? You would need only a single line using just `Rar.exe` on appending the date at end of file name before file extension by using the Rar/WinRAR option `-agYYYY-MM-DD` (international date format) and that's it. See text file `Rar.txt` in program files directory of WinRAR. That simple solution would be also independent on the country/region set for the user account used on running the batch file.

Comment: BTW: `for /f %%a in ('date /t') do set "DAY=%%a"` and `set "DAY=%DAY:/=_%"` is the worst method to get and format the current locale date for usage in a file name. It is ridiculous to start with `for` a new command process in background to execute the command `date` with option `/T`, capture this output, process it with `for`, assign it to an environment variable, and then replace all `/` by `_` in date string. Exactly the same can be done with just `set "DAY=%DATE:/=_%"` by `cmd.exe` already running for processing the batch file line by line whereby `%DATE:/=_%` could be even used directly.

Comment: In other words `@"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -r -df "C:\Temp\DATA%DATE:/=_%Backup.rar" "C:\Temp\*Backup.bak"` is a single line replacement for your entire batch file as well as much better `@"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -agYYYY-MM-DD -ep1 -r -df "C:\Temp\DATA_Backup_.rar" "C:\Temp\*Backup.bak"` with storing the files matching the pattern `*Backup.bak` without path in file `C:\Temp\DATA_Backup_YYYY-MM-DD.rar`. International date format has the big advantage that file names with `YYYY-MM-DD` sorted by name are at the same time sorted chronological.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe replace `/` to `_` and also let's use set correctly for directory paths with possible whitespace:

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in ('date /t') do set "DAY=%%a"
set "DAY=%DAY:/=_%"
set "rarFile=C:\temp\DATA%DAY%Backup.rar"
echo "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar" a -r -df "%rarFile%" "C:\temp\*Backup.bak"
pause
```

This will only `echo` the command for now, so once you are happy it works, remove `echo` from the last line.